# Returned value is null when downloading a file from OneDrive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, live-sdk

As it is said in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659730.aspx), I try to download a file way:

```
try
{
    LiveDownloadOperation operation = await connectClient.CreateBackgroundDownloadAsync(filePath);
    var result = await operation.StartAsync();
    var file = result.File; // It is null

}
catch
{
    // Handle errors.
}
```

But `result.File` is null. I think something is wrong with my file path, which is like this:

`path = "file.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!129"`

also tried:
`path = "file.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!129/content"`

what is the wrong? *it is a windows runtime app, using LiveSDK 5.6*

Comment: Is either `Stream` or `GetRandomAccessStreamAsync` not null?

Answer (score 1):

To read the file content, use the file ID + /content and then access the stream.

example:

```
LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(liveSession);
LiveDownloadOperation operation = 
         await liveClient.CreateBackgroundDownloadAsync(fileId + "/content");
var operationResult = await operation.StartAsync();

var fileContent = 
         await CustomMethod(await operationResult.GetRandomAccessStreamAsync());

return fileContent;
```