# LiveConnectClient does not contain a definition for DownloadAsync.

Tags: winrt-xaml

I am writing a Universal App with VS2013 update 2. But it looks like DownloadAsync was deprecated as I get the compile error: Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectClient' does not contain a definition for 'DownloadAsync'

```
LiveConnectClient clientLocal = new LiveConnectClient(client.Session);
var downloadResult = await clientLocal.DownloadAsync(string.Format("{0}/content", folderId));
```

A recent solution had me try that code so it must have worked in VS2012?? See link:
[OneDrive Upload/Download to Specified Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715282/onedrive-upload-download-to-specified-directory#)

Any working examples using the latest VS2013 and Microsoft.Live?

Answer (score 0):

For LiveConnect SDK 5.6 WinRT WP8.1 DownloadAsync is not available. I went with the solution at:
[Returned value is null when downloading a file from OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704052/returned-value-is-null-when-downloading-a-file-from-onedrive/24159776#comment37716519_24159776)